# Why does CacheManager receives code 202 for MapQuest?

Tags: osmdroid

I notice that it seems impossible to use the CacheManager with the tiles source MapQuest, it receives http code 202 and doesn't download the tiles.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran across on this on the osm mailing list

> MapQuest is moving to a 100% cloud solution - the new infrastructure dictates that all tile access will require a key. Details on how to get keys, SDKs and general migration information is below:
>
> On Monday, July 11, 2016, our direct tile access to MapQuest legacy maps will be discontinued. After Monday, July 11, 2016, we’ll require those using our direct tiles access to sign up for a plan on the Developer Network and transition to one of our four mapping solutions:
>   MapQuest plugin for Leaflet
>   iOS mobile SDK
>   Android mobile SDK
>   Static map API
>
> Get new keys and SDKs here:  https://developer.mapquest.com/

I'd bet this is the reason