# osmdroid error downloading Maptile

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, offline, osmdroid

I have a problem using the osmdroid

when I use this code

```
map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
```

I have no problem using the online map. But this does not allow me to use the offline map from sd.

As such, I changed to

```
map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapQuest", 0, 18, 256, ".jpg", new String[]{}));
```

This allows me to load the offline map, but I cannot receive online map at the same time,

I get this error:

```
Error downloading MapTile: /18/130173/86895
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
      at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
      at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.OnlineTileSourceBase.getBaseUrl(OnlineTileSourceBase.java:33)
      at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource.getTileURLString(XYTileSource.java:19)
      at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader$TileLoader.loadTile(MapTileDownloader.java:178)
      at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase$TileLoader.run(MapTileModuleProviderBase.java:291)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am sure I have permission for the internet, may I know how can I use online and offline map at the same time is osmdroid?

Comment: Note there's an open issues with MapQuest, see https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/332 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818511/why-does-cachemanager-receives-code-202-for-mapquest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing to this line.

map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapQuest", 0, 18, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {
            "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
            "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/"}));

Hope it helps other people who has the same problem